# Reduce Youtube quality to 144p using Selenium(Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can I reduce the quality of a Youtube video being played by the Chrome Webdriver through Selenium(Python)? The `setPlaybackQuality` function in Javascript is no longer supported.
Currently I am setting the playback speed of the video to 16x so that the quality automatically gets switched to 144p.

However most of the times, this doesn't happen and the video keeps playing in a higher resolution, usually 360p. Is there any other approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.ytp-button.ytp-settings-button').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Quality')]").click()

time.sleep(2)   # you can adjust this time
quality = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(string(),'144p')]")
print("Element is visible? " + str(quality.is_displayed()))

quality.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in .net.
The working code for .net is:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(string(),'144p')]")).Click();
```